# Segmentation fault while decoding the audio(mp3) file using C API

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am executing [decode_audio.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_audio.c) file. I compiled it successfully. I am getting segmentation fault when I execute. I included the avformat.h header file. I changed the codec logic according to mp3 format. I am using the following command to compile and execute.

```
mycode$ gcc -o decode_audio decode_audio.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lz -lm
mycode$ ./decode_audio audio.mp3 raw.bin
```

What is the reason for this segmentation fault in my program?

You can see my modified program [here](https://ideone.com/fork/vxlNKy).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ffmpeg 3.4.4 versions. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should step through the code in debugger and see where it crashes.

Comment: Yes, I did debugging. Its not going forward after avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame); inside while loop of decode function, still facing the issue, how can I get rid off this.

Comment: You modified `decode_audio.c`? You should show your code.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509284/mp3-decoding-using-ffmpeg-api-header-missing

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I edited the question, you can check now. Please help through this.

Comment: @kamilz I have seen that, and I cant understand what it says, can you explain it simpler.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have added the code, please check it once.